# Convert JS regex to not use lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

Early in the development of a web project I work on I created this regex `/(?<!\\)\w?\$.+?(?<!\\)\$/` which aims to match `$ any text here$` as long as the first and last `$` are not preceded by `\`.

A few examples are shown here https://regex101.com/r/Y1Uml9/1/

The regex works perfectly until I realised that iOS Safari and Chrome do not support lookbehinds. I tried to modify the regex myself but my basic regex skills were not able to produce a working one.

Any suggestions how to convert the regex so it works on iOS?

Comment: It should be `/(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*\$([^\\$]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\$]*)*)\$/g` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMkYEs/1/)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks works almost perfectly. [This](https://regex101.com/r/3bpgag/1/) also matches the space or the character before the first `$` (you can see this from the last line of the regex101). Can you modify it so it does not catch that character or whitespace before the `$`?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to "not catch that character". You do not need to worry about that. What you need to worry is: are you 1) extracting matches or 2) replacing matches? Or 3) splitting?

Comment: I am replacing the matches - the whole `$match here$` with something else. That is why I need to preserve the space or whatever character it is before the replacement string is put otherwise the resulting text will look weird

Comment: So, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/aMkYEs/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\$([^\\$]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\$]*)*)\$/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMkYEs/2/).

Basically, capture the part before the "actual" match, capture the part of the match you need to keep when replacing.

*Details*:

- `((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)` - Group 1: start of string or any char other than `\` and then zero or more repetitions of double backslash
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `([^\\$]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\$]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^\\$]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` and `$`
- `(?:\\[\w\W][^\\$]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\\[\w\W]` - a `\` followed with any char
  - `[^\\$]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` and `$`
- `\$` - a `$` char

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\$([^\\$]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\$]*)*)\$/g;
const str = String.raw`$ some test here$
$ some text here with inner \$ $
\$ this should not be matched\$`;
console.log( str.replace(regex, '$1<<START>>$2<<END>>') );
```